# Accessing data from external tenant - Sharepoint

Tags: azure, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I am still relatively new to data analysis in my current role / organisation.

We would like to access data from an external tenant SharePoint, and store it within our own tenant.

What would be the best practice to achieve this?

We have an azure directory, but I don't really know how to use this.

(Would be able to discuss / learn Azure if this would provide the best solution)

So far I have only used Power Query to pull data into our own tenant.

Kind Regards

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that you want to share SharePoint sites with external users.

Here are steps:

1.Enable external sharing in the tenant level. Go to SharePoint admin center -> Polices -> Sharing -> Set Anyone.

[image]

2.Enable external sharing in the site level. Go to SharePoint admin center -> Sites -> Active sites -> Select the site you want to share -> Sharing -> Set Anyone.

[image]

3.Share SharePoint sites with external users. Go to Site settings -> Site permissions -> Share site only.

[image]